# Setting of POSTFIX or SENDMAIL from MAMP and MAC OS SIERRA

Tags: php, macos, mamp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I am looking for someone to help me to configure `POSTFIX` or `SENDMAIL` from `MAMP` and **MAC OS SIERRA** in order to test PHP `mail()` locally. I am struggling since few days ! But still unable to make anything working.

I do try some change in `php.ini` used by `MAMP` as follows.

Then I modified the file `main.cf` in `/etc/postfix`.

I specify I am beginner in coding ;-)

Thanks for your understanding

Comment: problem solved with this post https://gist.github.com/kany/c44c077881047ead8faa

Answer (score 0):

Postfix is basically broken in Sierra.

**Solution is to upgrade to High Sierra.**

Or put it this way, you can have a correct config, and it will not work, in Sierra.

Here's a little more information:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412895/how-to-fix-postfix-on-macos-sierra-10-12-6?rq=1&newreg=d74c5f8df597424a861a6adc81e68faa

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in the main.cf solved the same problem on Sierra 10.12.6

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
```

and this but I am not sure:

```
compatibility_level = 2
```